# MVC EditorFor and ID generator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, editorfor

I have a ViewModel with rows repeated by using a EditorTemplate

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Rows)
```

The HTML generated looks like this (only 1 field in this sample)

```
<input id="Rows_0__Comment" name="Rows[0].Comment" type="text" value="a" />
<input id="Rows_1__Comment" name="Rows[1].Comment" type="text" value="b" />
<input id="Rows_2__Comment" name="Rows[2].Comment" type="text" value="c" />
```

This is all fine. But I have a server round trip where some logic removes X rows.

```
model.Rows = model.Rows.Where(x => x.WhatEver()).ToList();
```

Now the index based ID strategy used in the HTML render doesn't align with what is posted. So values can be posted to the wrong row.

Can I customize the ID generator to use a ID from my model?

Comment: use just <input type='text' id='' name='' />

Comment: ModelState.Clear() fixes the problem